# pipenv creating of virtual env getting errors

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm very new to pipenv but I've realised that I'm having a very odd problem.

I have setup WORKON_HOME.

When I create a directory (say testing_app), cd into it and run

```
> pipenv install
```

I get this error:

```
▶ pipenv install
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✘ Locking Failed!
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches requrest
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches requrest
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches requrest
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches requrest
No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
```

There is no Pipfile created. And a virtual directory called desmondlim_mm-XXXX is created.

But when I do (this is a work around).

```
> touch Pipfile
```

and run

```
> pipenv install
```

Everything is fine. The virtualenv called testing_app-XXXX and the Pipfile.lock is created.

I'm running MacOS Mojave and intalled pipenv using brew.

Anyone encountered this issue? More importantly, how to solve it?

Desmond

Comment: I am also getting the same error, did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit Pipfile like this:
from

```
pyyaml = "*"
requests = "==2.21.0"
```

to:

```
pyyaml = "*"
requests = "*"
```

or requests = "~=2.2" if you want versions from 2.0-2.99

or simply execute this wothout editing Pipfile:

```
$ pipenv install "requests~=2.2"  # locks the major version of the package (this is equivalent to using ==2.*)
```

for more info, refer to https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#specifying-versions-of-a-package